# Load giving me error SQL3192N for my dateformat

Tags: db2-luw

I am trying to load data into db2 using the following command and get errors.

db2 load client from 5rec.csv of del replace into t1

SQL0180N  The syntax of the string representation of a datetime value is
incorrect.  SQLSTATE=22007

SQL3185W  The previous error occurred while processing data from row "F0-1" of
the input file.

my dates are either null or of the format 30/8/1938 which is D/M/YYYY so I tried the following but still get errors.

db2 load client from 5rec.csv of del modified by dateformat="D/M/YYYY" replace into T1

SQL3192N  In the filetmod a user specified format "DATEFORMAT" beginning with
the string "D/M/YYYY" is not valid.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: We cannot see your raw data to verify the format, but have you tried using `dateformat="DD/M/YYYY" ?  ( note the double D, instead of the single D in your question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must escape double quotes, if you run such a command from a shell.
Try the following:

```
db2 "load client from 5rec.csv of del modified by dateformat=\"D/M/YYYY\" replace into T1"
```